# awk to remove lines if column not in another file

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` I am trying to remove those lines in `f2` `$1` that do not match `f1` `$1`. The `awk` does execute but it prints all the lines not the desired output. Thank you :).

**awk**

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{map[$1]=1;next;}map[$1]==$1{print;}' f1 f2
```

**f1**

```
ACTA2
ADA
AIP
```

**f2**

```
ADA
AG11
AIP
```

**desired**

```
ADA
AIP
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no placeholders) with field separators and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `map[$1]=$8` is an assignment; `map[$1]==$8` is a test (note the double `=`); if your code does not work after making that change, do as Cyrus has asked, eg, provide sample inputs *without* the placeholders (`...`)

Comment: I edited the input as `==` did not produce any results, though it did execute. Thank you :).

Comment: Regarding `it prints all the lines` - no, that script does not do that. This is by far the most frequently asked and answered question on this forum, asked a couple of times a week, please look in the archives.

Comment: For example, just look at the awk scripts in the answers in the results of [googling your subject line](https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+to+remove+lines+if+column+not+in+another+file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {array[$1]=$1; next} {if($1 == array[$1]) print}' file1 file2
ADA
AIP
```

Comment: Thank you very much :).

Comment: While this will produce the expected output from the posted sample input, it's not actually the right answer as it's lengthier and more complicated than necessary, uses [potentially a lot] more memory than necessary in a couple of different ways, and would print any lines from `file2` that are empty or are numerically zero regardless if they exist in `file1` or not.

Comment: @EdMorton As always, your input is appreciated. I have learned much from you and will always be willing to learn more. Feel free to either edit my answer or provide another. : )

Comment: @HatLess glad you took the feedback as constructive as intended. I really want the OP to learn how to look for existing answers in the forum rather than providing an answer to this so that next time they don't need to ask. This particular question has been beaten to death and literally comes up multiple times a week.

Comment: Thank you all, I will search for an existing answer an appreciate your help as I continue to learn :).